# add new contact to group using google people API with python

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-contacts-api

I am trying to create a code that saves new contacts and puts them in a certain group.

Creating a contact works great-

```
service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
service.people().createContact(body={"names": [{"givenName": name}], "phoneNumbers": [{'value': phone}],}).execute()
```

There is no problem in creating a group either-

```
service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
a = service.contactGroups().create(body={"contactGroup": {"name": "try1123", }}).execute()
```

But when I try to create a contact within the group I encounter an unknown error-

```
    service.people().createContact(body={"names": [{"givenName": name}], "phoneNumbers": [{'value': phone_number}],
                                     "memberships": [{"contactGroupMembership": {
                                         "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/'try1123'", }, }]}).execute()
```

error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact?alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "Request contains an invalid argument.">
```

[createContact python code](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.people.html#createContact)

[createContact Method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is where the `{contactGroupId}` you are specifying in  `contactGroupResourceName`, you are putting the `name` of the contact group you created, the `id` should be an `int` value for what can I see in the examples, something like `"contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/123123123"`

Most likely the call when you created the `contactGroup` should have returned you this `id`.

Comment: It should not be an int, in my case it was 29f079748cfd14d0.
The last sentence you wrote helped me a lot, thank you very much!!